# ROR: View only form fields

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, forms

Is there any way that you can mark a form field to be only accessible in the view?

I have some 'helper' fields that I use in conjunction with jQuery to build and order certain elements in the view. These fields don't need to be passed through to the controller and are not linked to the model at all.

I'm just wondering if there is some attribute I can use with the ROR form fields to mark them as obsolete.

Currently I am just using vanilla form fields.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe `FormTagHelper` ([doc](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/FormTagHelper.html)) may help you. With this helper you can create html inputs outside of a form (this way the value of these input fields won't be sent to the controller).

Comment: Thanks, thats exactly what I was looking for. a ROR alternative :)

Answer (score 1):

HTML provides a 'disabled' attribute for all form elements which exclude them from submission. Use that, or do a pre-submit check using javascript which removes the attributes from the form submission.

Answer (score 0):

To expand upon Archit Baweja's answer, disabled BUTTON, INPUT, OPTGROUP, OPTION, SELECT, and TEXTAREA tags are not submitted with the form. More information on disabled elements can be found here: http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/interact/forms.html#h-17.12

Additionally, if you have any security concerns of these inputs being mass assigned in the controller via "upodate_attributes(params), then you can guard against this end user assignment using attr_accessible. You may call this method and pass the parameter names you would like to white list, and allow to pass through when using update_attributes:

```
class AccountsController < ApplicationController
  include ActiveModel::MassAssignmentSecurity

  attr_accessible :first_name, :last_name
  attr_accessible :first_name, :last_name, :plan_id, :as => :admin

  def update
    ...
    @account.update_attributes(account_params)
    ...
  end

  protected

  def account_params
    role = admin ? :admin : :default
    sanitize_for_mass_assignment(params[:account], role)
  end

end
```

More information on the MassAssignmentSecurity module can be found here: http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveModel/MassAssignmentSecurity/ClassMethods.html